# CXF web service client: CallbackHandler

Tags: cxf, webservice-client

We have a web service client, developed using Apache CXF.
Inside our client class, we have this:

```
public class RunCode implements CallbackHandler
{

   @Test
   public void getView()
   {
       // Code     
   }

}
```

Now my **question** is: in which cases our classes need to implement the `CallbackHandler`?
And in the above code what is it doing exactly?

Comment: What is 'CallbackHandler'? I can't imagine any case in which a JUnit test would need to or want to implement such a thing.

Comment: CallbackHandler is a interface from javax.security.auth.callback ,

Answer (score 0):

CallbackHandler is used with WS-SECURITY and WS-SECURITYPOLICY. See [this documentation of CXF WS-SECURITY](http://cxf.apache.org/docs/ws-security.html). You would not make a unit test class implement it unless for some complex reason you chose to pass the 'this' of your unit test into CXF as the callback object, which would be a rather baroque design for a unit test if you ask me.